# Unable to Encode Unicode Beautiful Soup Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This script is unable to print/write Unicode characters. The output return these characters
*ÚØ±Ø§ÙÛ Ù¹Ú¾ÛÚØ§ Ø¯Ø§ ÙØ±Ú©Ø²Û Ø®ÛØ§Ù ÙÚ©Ú¾Ù.*
I don't know what I'm doing wrong?.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
addresses = ['https://alyabdulah.com/Ilm-Short-Questions-Raw/09th-Bio-EM-U1.html', 'https://alyabdulah.com/Ilm-Short-Questions-Raw/10th-Punjabi-UM-U5.html']
subjects = ['09th-Bio-EM-U1-', '10th-Punjabi-UM-U5-']
for runscript in range(0, len(addresses)):
    response = requests.get(addresses[runscript])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    ques_id = soup.find_all('div', class_='q-title')
    ques_det = soup.find_all('div', class_='q-desc')
    optn_det = soup.find_all('div', class_='choose-answer-block')
    #Writing in File and Saving
    #FileVar = open('files/{}.txt'.format(subjects[runscript]), 'w', encoding='utf-8')
    for i in range(0, len(ques_id)):
        unformated_ques_id = (ques_id[i].text)
        formated_ques_id = unformated_ques_id.replace("Question #  ", subjects[runscript])
        print(formated_ques_id) # Getting Question Number
        print('\t')
        print(str(ques_det[i].text).strip()) # Getting Question Text
        print('\t')
        print(optn_det[i].text.strip()) # Getting Answer Text
        print('<----->\n')
    print('{} Done Successfully'.format(subjects[runscript]))
    #FileVar.close()
```

Comment: Please reduce the code to a [mre]. I.e., limit to one URL and one question #.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.content` not `.text` from the `requests`.

For example:

```py
for runscript in range(0, len(addresses)):
    response = requests.get(addresses[runscript])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')  # change .text -> .content
```

This change in the code produces the following output:

```
ڈرامہ ٹھیڈا دا مرکزی خیال لکھو.
    
ایس ڈرامے وچ دسیا گیا اے ' کہ حرام دی دولت تے عیش کرن نالوں ایمانداری دی سکی روٹی چنگی اے . جت وی ہمیشہ ایمانداری دی ہوندی اے . حلال دی کمائی وچ برکت ہوندی اے . رزق حلال کھان والے دے گھر وچ سکون تے پیار ہوندا اے.
```

If this doesn't (somehow) help, you might want to swap the encoding by adding this line:

```
response.encoding = response.apparent_encoding
```